# Custom price for cart item not converting based on currency Magento 2

Tags: php, product, customization, cart, magento-2.3

When I am going to add custom price to cart item by below method in checkout_cart_product_add_after Observer and it's works fine but when I am going to change currency from cart then value not converted as per rate so any other way to add custom cart item price to cart.

```
$customPrice = $getSlectedAttrOptions['current_price'];
$item->setCustomPrice($origCustomPrice);
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($origCustomPrice);
$item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

Comment: $customPrice = $getSlectedAttrOptions['current_price'];
you  have to convert to custom price to desire currency before you set to product

Comment: reference => https://aureatelabs.com/magento-2/how-to-convert-the-price-from-one-currency-to-another-in-the-magento-2/

Comment: Like this $origCustomPrice = $this->_customizationHelper->convertPrice($customPrice,$currentCurrency,$baseCurrency);?

Comment: Yes @Tarunmodi.

Comment: Still it's showing same for all currency

Comment: you need to find base currency code and then find current currency code...then convert price from base currency to current currency after then you can use your code:

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12493#issuecomment-352038477

It seems that custom price is used only in admin area and no currency change is taken into account.

You could try [this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/27161#issuecomment-611488154) or [this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12493#issue-278055454) (not helpful in my experience, and editing core files is not our best).